# How can I run ImageAI on my GPU and not my CPU

Tags: tensorflow, conda, image-recognition, custom-training, imageai

So I am quite new to this I was trying to find answers on google but it is kind of not working. So I am trying to run this library [ImageAI library](https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI)

I am able to run it normally on the CPU at least I think it runs on CPU by just calling python test.py. Am I correct there

But since the model prediction takes a long time I would like to run it on my GPU. What I was trying to do is create a conda environment and activate it but after I do I get this error.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageai.Classification'`

Although I have imageai installed in my environment

```
pip freeze | findstr imageai
imageai==2.1.5
```

As you can see by executing this command. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/55

Comment: And there are several other articles [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+%27imageai.Classification).

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes but it isn't the same issue. One doesn't recognize the library at all mine does but not the modules

Comment: I think you should try following the advice at those articles anyway.  They explain how to use pip properly.  Package managers exist because they help prevent dependency problems like yours.

Comment: @RobertHarvey will take a more closer look at the articles I already did but maybe I have missed something. But I installed every requirement for this library as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution it doesnt require the conda environment. ImageAI automatically runs on GPU if available. All you need to do is to ensure you have the GPU version of Tensorflow installed.